# Migrate Transport Client to RestHighLevelClient Search Query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, resthighlevelclient

I am new in elastic search. I have to migrate search query from Transport client to RestHighLevelClient.

Below is the code with Transport client which I need to migrate.

```java
SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = Client.prepareSearch(elasticsearchIndex);
    
            try {
                searchRequestBuilder.
                        setQuery(generateBoolQuery(keyword))
                        .setFrom(0).setSize(100).setExplain(true)
                        .execute().actionGet();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.debug(errorMessage, ex);
                throw new BadKeywordFormatException("Keyword \'" + keyword + "\' has " + "Unsupported characters. ", ex);
            } 


I have written corresponding code as 

     SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(elasticsearchIndex);
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(generateBoolQuery(keyword));
        searchSourceBuilder.from(0).size(100).explain(true);
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse;
        try {
             searchResponse = elasticsearchClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.debug(errorMessage, e);
            throw new BadKeywordFormatException("Keyword \'" + keyword + "\' has " + "Unsupported characters. ", e);
        }
```

Please let me know what's wrong with this code ? Please help me with correct corresponding code .

I am attaching error logs  I am getting while executing this query.

**Error Log**

```
Exception in thread "main" ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]]
        at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1727)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:1704)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1467)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1424)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1394)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:930)



================================================================================================


        Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [https://localhost:9200], URI [/index_name/_search?typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512&ccs_minimize_roundtrips=true], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"filter\" : [\n      {\n        \"bool\" : {\n          \"should\" : [\n            {\n              \"regexp\" : {\n                \"name\" : {\n                  \"value\" : \"/\\\\b(?:\\\\d[ -]*?){13,16}\\\\b/\",\n                  \"flags_value\" : 65535,\n                  \"max_determinized_states\" : 10000,\n                  \"boost\" : 1.0\n                }\n              }\n            }\n          ],\n          \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}","index_uuid":"wPZPF4RH2gMlH","index":"index_name"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"index_name","node":"jKaYqlQwCHqlch","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"filter\" : [\n      {\n        \"bool\" : {\n          \"should\" : [\n            {\n              \"regexp\" : {\n                \"name\" : {\n                  \"value\" : \"/\\\\b(?:\\\\d[ -]*?){13,16}\\\\b/\",\n                  \"flags_value\" : 65535,\n                  \"max_determinized_states\" : 10000,\n                  \"boost\" : 1.0\n                }\n              }\n            }\n          ],\n          \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n          \"boost\" : 1.0\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}","index_uuid":"wPZPF4RH2gMlH","index":"index_name","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"expected ']' at position 25"}}}]},"status":400}
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:253)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:231)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:205)
                at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454)
```

Thanks in advance